# How do you close port

Tags: socket

I've got the same problem as mentioned here

[nc: bind failed: Address already in use](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121230/nc-bind-failed-address-already-in-use)

i.e.

```
$ nc -l 3206
Ncat: bind to :::3206: Address already in use. QUITTING.
```

Can someone give a 1 line command without pages of explanations, references and alternative methods, on how you free up this port...

Answer (score 5):

There's a process that uses that port, and you will not be able to bind to that port until that process has closed its connection.

To find out what process is holding the port:

```bsh
sudo lsof -i :3206
```

If it's a process that you think you may be able to terminate without causing any loss of data, then just use `kill pid` (possibly with `sudo` if it's root's process), where `pid` is the process ID reported by `lsof`.

Comment: Not necessarily. It may also be an earlier instance of any command including the `nc -l` itself, where the port is in a `TIME_WAIT` state. If this is the case you have to wait a short while until the port is released. Check with `netstat -nap | grep :3206`

Comment: ... unless `nc` sets `SO_REUSEADDR` ...

Comment: @thrig `nc` on OpenBSD sets `SO_REUSEPORT`. This implementation is available on Linux too I think (`netcat-openbsd` in Ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

You can see what processes are on port.

```
netstat -tulpn
```

Comment: You might want to explain that a bit. The `-p` flag requires a protocol name as argument on OpenBSD, and the command, as it stands, lists no processes on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Did you forget `sudo`?